# After server change simple html dom doesn't work anymore

Tags: php, foreach, fatal-error, simple-html-dom

After transferring my previously working code on 5.6 PHP to a new host and server with PHP 7.2, I'm now getting this `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on array ...`. How do I fix this?

```
<?php
// Get Source
$html = file_get_html('URL');

// Get needed table
$table = $html->find('table',1);

// Find each row, starting with the 2nd, and echo the Cells
foreach($table->find('tr') as $rowNumber => $row) {

  if ( $rowNumber < 1 ) continue; 

  $cell = $row->find('td', 0)->plaintext;
  echo $cell;

  $cell2 = $row->find('td', 1)->plaintext;
  echo $cell2;

}
?>
```

UPDATE
So it seems the source of the error is the `file_get_html` code which doesn't work perfectly with PHP 7.

I've found two go-arounds:

1) Through curl

```
// Curl-Verbindung zu HTM-Datei
 $base = 'FULL PATH';
 $curl = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $base);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $base);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
 $str = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);
    // Create a DOM object
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    // Load HTML from a string
    $html->load($str);
```

2) Another through `str_get_html`

```
$html = str_get_html(file_get_contents('RELATIVE PATH'));
```

I guess the second is better?

Comment: Have you tried to echo out before the error? e.g. what does the `$table` return, what do you get as the `$rowNumber` and `$row`?

Comment: @scunliffe Interestingly it returns an empty array if I echo `$table`. I've checked the file. It's in the right place and it would generate an error on bool, if not. If I echo `$html` it returns nothing. So there should be something wrong...

Comment: Is this the same code you're running on your server, without any modifications? Did you check the url? What's stored in `$html` after calling `file_get_html`?

Comment: Nothing. If I echo `$html` it returns blank space. If I change the php-version to 5.6 it works again. It returns the complete source file. So is there anything to watch out for in the new php version combined with simple_html_dom?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [simplehtmldom Call to a member function find() on array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45889363/simplehtmldom-call-to-a-member-function-find-on-array)

Answer (score 0):

Just check the file URL on line 3.

**$html = file_get_html('URL');**

Try to use absolute URL if you are using a relative one.